# Committing Transaction at the Beginning of Trigger Logic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a trigger on a table (`AFTER INSERT, UPDATE`) which exists to compute values based on what has been added or updated to the table, and store them in a separate table.

I've read quite a bit around error handling inside triggers, and the fact that errors in my trigger logic will `ROLLBACK` the original transaction which called the trigger in the first place.

In order to preserve the original transaction at all costs (assuming that at some point, the trigger could fail) I began my code by doing something like this;

```
-- Grab newly inserted data
SELECT          *
INTO            #Temp
FROM            INSERTED

-- Force transaction to finish, making sure following statements don't roll it back
COMMIT          TRAN

-- Continue using data stored in #Temp
UPDATE          .....
SET             .....
FROM            #Temp
```

This worked, even when I put intentional errors in the trigger logic, the question, is this safe?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it is safe or not. But as an alternative, depending on what exactly you are doing, you could do your insert or update and then receive the inserted data with using OUTPUT and use these data to do your trigger logic. Like this you wouldn't need a trigger, but really depends on your environment (it might be a little bit slower like this than the trigger approach):

```
-- update row status (in progress)

update Staging.GFTIntradayLivePricesStaging
set Status = 1 -- in progress
output INSERTED.GFTIntradayLivePricesStagingID into @RowsTransfered
where GFTIntradayLivePricesStaging.Status = 0 -- not processed
and exists
            (
                select top 1 1
                from Portfolio.Objects.Objects
                where GFTInstrumentID = GFTIntradayLivePricesStaging.GFTInstrumentID
            )
```

About output:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx